# Probability of getting an odd sum.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the probability that when I sum the first eight prime numbers that I get an odd total.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how the number 2 factors into all of this seeings as its the only even prime number.

Comment: As the question is written, the sum of the first eight primes is odd, and so the probability is $100$%.

Comment: There's only one outcome for summing the first eight prime numbers - an odd number.

Comment: `sum the first eight prime numbers` $= 2 + \text{sum of next 7 prime numbers}\,$. All prime numbers greater than $2$ are odd. Sum of $7$ odd numbers is $\;\cdots\;$

Comment: You guys rock! Thank you all for the prompt response!

Comment: Not only does it have a 100% chance of being odd.  It has a 100% chance of equaling exactly 77.  This is a very weird question.

Comment: you know, pointing out that 7 odds and an even is odd, is one thing, but maybe we should also point out "the sum of the first 8 primes" is specifically 2 + 3+ 5+7+11+13+17+19" which consistantly is one value. Probability doesn't come into play.  It has a 100% prod of being odd.  It also has a 100% probability of being divisible by 11.  And a 0% chance of be divisible by 3.  etc.

Answer (score 3):

The 7 primes after $2$ will give you an odd total, since all primes (after $2$) are odd and an odd number of odd numbers will total to an odd number.

Adding the first prime -- $2$ -- to this total changes nothing. You still have an odd total.

So the outcome is guaranteed -- the total of the first eight primes will be an odd number.